# ngb-pagination shows as first page, cannot set the page number, programmatically

Tags: angular, pagination, ngb-pagination

I am using ngb pagination

following is the code:

```
      <ngb-pagination class='float-right' [maxSize]=10
                                                        (pageChange)="currentPage=$event;paginationNavigation('pagination');"
                                                        [collectionSize]="totalobjects" [(pageSize)]="pageSize"
                                                        [(page)]="currentPage" aria-label="Default pagination">
      </ngb-pagination>
```

I am getting currentPage value from query params:

```
const params  = this._route.snapshot.queryParams
this.currentPage=parseInt(params['currentPage']) || 1;
```

But this doesn't set the pagination html value when refreshing/loading the page,it shows as first page.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't change the page not work put in ngOnInit `const params  = this._route.snapshot.queryParams` because the ngOnInit it's not execute again else you refresh the navigator or when change the page (I want to say that you are in `/default` and go to `/product-list/2`, but ngOnInit it's not execute again if you're in `product-list/1` and go to `product-list/2`)

You need [subscribe to ActivatedRoute.queryParams](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information)

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.currentPage = (+params['currentPage']) || 1;
  });
}
```

NOTE: be sure you are defined your route as `path: 'product-list/:currentPage'`

Comment: I added your code, but still the same issue